# Check dictionary's values are included in another dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries like below. What I want to do is checking that all `a`'s values are included in `b` dictionary. Two dictionaries may be different structure. And some `a`'s keys are not included in `b`. I want to know generic ways to realize this.

**Check value list. All `a`'s values should be included in `b`**

Expected outputs are like below text output. I know `a[0].name` is not valid in python. This is not python's raw code.

- `a[0]['name']` in `b`? => yes, same value
- `a[0]['vals'][0]['apple']` in `b`? => yes, but different value
- `a[0]['vals'][0]['banana'][0]['hoge']` in `b`? => not exists
- `a[0]]'vals'][0]['banana'][0]['fuga']` in `b`? => not exits

Two dictionaries.

```
a = [
   {
      "name":"hoge",
      "vals":[
         {
            "apple":11,
            "banana":{
               "hoge":1,
               "fuga":"aaa"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]

b = [
   {
      "name":"hoge",
      "vals":[
         {
            "apple":21,
            "grape":{
               "foo":1
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: what output you are expecting??! and please correct your data structure it is faulty.

Comment: *If* your data structure was correct, you would access dictionary entries by `a[0]["name"]`.

Comment: You asked the wrong question. b's values are the string `"hoge"` and a list containin a dict containing two items.

Comment: You are basicly asking two - maybe three quesions:
1: How to get the leaf values in a nested dict?
2: How to check if an element is leaf element of a nested dict?
3: How to check if all elements of a given collection are values of a dict?
- You should really split this question up.

Comment: code format fix. In fact, there is a python 2 module call `jsontree` that will convert json like dict value to a dotted notation as what OP wrote.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a `dict` comparison function as I did below:

```
def compare_ndic(src, dst, pre=''):
    for skey, sval in src.items():
        if pre:
            print_skey = pre + '.' + skey
        else:
            print_skey = skey
        if skey not in dst.keys():
            print('Key "{}" in {} does not existed in {}'.format(print_skey, 'src', 'dst'))
        else:
            if isinstance(sval, dict) and isinstance(dst.get(skey), dict):
                #If the value of the same key is still dict
                compare_ndic(sval, dst.get(skey), print_skey)
            elif sval == dst.get(skey):
                print('Value of key "{}" in {} is the same with value in {}'.format(print_skey, 'src', 'dst'))
            else:
                print('Value of key "{}" in {} is different with value in {}'.format(print_skey, 'src', 'dst'))

a = {
    "name":"hoge",
    "vals":
    {
        "apple":11,
        "banana":{
           "hoge":1,
           "fuga":"aaa"
        }
    }
}

b = {
    "name": "hoge",
    "vals": 
    {
        "apple": 11,
        "banana": {
            "hoge": 2,
            "fuga": "aaa",
        }
    }
}
compare_ndic(a, b)
```

The output is like this:

```
Value of key "vals.banana.fuga" in src is the same with value in dst
Value of key "vals.banana.hoge" in src is different with value in dst
Value of key "vals.apple" in src is the same with value in dst
Value of key "name" in src is the same with value in dst
```

Be careful, my code cannot be used directly for your scenario, because you have `list` in your data. You can add some conditional statements and to iterate the whole list if necessary. Anyway, I've just provided an idea to compare two dicts, you need to modify it in your own way.

Comment: This is mostly what I want. I am trying to apply `list` value now.

Comment: Doesn't this assume and need same structures for `a` and `b`? It's a Marilyn vos Savants answer - correct but assuming soomething that is not in the quesion. On the other hand: without this assumption one can't answer the question at all.

Answer (score -1):

You have mistake in accessing method.
a is list which is accessed as

```
a[0]
```

but a[0] is dictionary which is accessed as

```
a[0]['vals']  # 'vals' is a key stored in dictionary
```

to only know keys in dictionary you can try

```
a[0].keys()  # gives you result dict_keys(['name', 'vals']) which you can iterate further as you wish
```

and you can get all elemnt using

```
a[0].items()  # gives you dict_items([('name', 'hoge'), ('vals', [{'banana': {'hoge': 1, 'fuga': 'aaa'}, 'apple': 21}])])
```

Moreover use correct syntax in code.
you have used incorrect syntax in your code

```
a = [{"name": "hoge", "vals": [{"apple": 21, "banana": {"hoge": 1, "fuga": "aaa"}}]}]

b = [{"name": "hoge", "vals": [{ "apple": 21, "grape": {"foo": 1}}]}]

if a[0]['name'] in b[0]['name']:
    print('first match')
    if a[0]['name'] == b[0]['name']:
        print('item exist with same value')
    else:
        print('item exist but not same value')

    for key in a[0]['vals'][0].keys():
        if key in b[0]['vals'][0].keys():
            print('second match with key : ' + str(key))
            if a[0]['vals'][0][str(key)] == b[0]['vals'][0][str(key)]:
                print('match exist with same value for key : ' + str(key))
        else:
            print('match failed for key : ' + str(key))

else:
    print('match failed at 1')
```

Comment: I know `a[0].name` is invalid in python.

Comment: then watch what you are asking before downvoting. your question deduce you don't know about list and dictionaries in python

Comment: And ths is not an answer. Bring this content into a comment and you get an upvote but there is 0% anser here.

Comment: if he match items with correct syntax like `a[0]['name'] in b[0]['name']` he can get result

Comment: Now it is an answer but still neither truely generic nor correct.